# How can i create a dialog-like transform without css but purely with Vue components?

Tags: vuetify.js

i wanted to ask how it is possible to create a scale-transition that is only slight, but without backface-culling like known from CSS3? But in Vue, with a list of individual v-cards or v-sheets from Vuetify.